# How does use of ThreadStatic affect the performance of IIS

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis

I want to use ThreadStatic atrribute in my code. I want to know if there will be some performance issue in IIS if I use ThreadStatic attribute in my application as multiple threads are going to access those fields . So I want to get idea if the resources of IIS are overused or any another thing I should keep in mind before implementing this.

Comment: hope this one helps https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/07/20/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0/

Comment: You probably *don't* want to use `ThreadStatic`. At most, you'd probably want to use something that has a lifetime linked to a *session* or a *request*. Neither of those is necessarily tied to a single *thread*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct performance issue using ThreadStatic through IIS, but you have to take in consideration that IIS use a thread pool.

It means that your thread static is not free after a single call.

In an other hand, a web request can be composed by multiple threads executions (page for example but not web service) and may not share the same thread for a same "client request".

If you don't free yourself the ThreadStatic thing, it may cost memory usage.

If you valuate a ThreadStatic in a synchronous method that call only synchronous process and free it in a finally block at end of the same method, you can use it without any side effect.